# How to check Azure VM Port Heatbeat

Tags: azure, monitoring, virtual-machines, ping

I have an application providing http services in a specific port (eg: 8181).

This app is autonomous and independent of IIS and any other application server. It is installed in a Azure VM.

I want to check if this app stopped or have some crash. I would like some kind of monitoring it in the Azure, like a "ping" check, for each 5 seconds for example, but in this specific port.

Is it possible to do that using Azure monitoring system? Does someone know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [Azure Network Watcher](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/network-watcher/network-watcher-monitoring-overview)
 or with [PsPing tool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psping)